# How to implement 'either-or' scenario in left outer joins in SQL

Tags: sql

I am a newbie in SQL queries and am really struggling with the following query.

I have to implement something like this:

```
Select person.name, person.age, employee.yearsofservice

from person

join employee on person.name = employee.name

join fulltimeemployed on person.name = fulltimeemployed.name

join parttimeemployed on person.name = parttimeemployed.name

where fulltimeemployed.manager = 'Rob'  or parttimeemployed.manager = 'Rob'
```

Basically I want to extract a list of all full time and part time employees who has their manager as 'Rob'.

But the above query gives empty result since the employee cannot be present in both fulltimeemployed as well as parttime employed table.

So I need a way to implement a OR clause between those 2 joins (fulltimeemployed and parttimeemployed). Please suggest any ideas :(

Comment: As @Wil mentioned - It's a _**terrible**_ idea to join on names; especially on something which is _usually_ a nick-name.  I also have serious reservations about your apparent table structure - what happens once someone is in both the `fulltime` and `parttime` tables?

Comment: I have to second (or is it third) the idea of changing your structure. As it stands right now this is not a workable structure. If you were doing this for a class, I'd give you an F. If you are doing it for work, I'd fire you. That is how bad this structure is. Names are not unique and they change over time therefore they are not a candidate for a PK.  Full time or part time can be handled by one field in the employees table as can the manager. The chances of having bad data in a structure like this approaches 100% over time as people change from fulto prat time and back.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the flaws in the design. I shall redesign the table bearing these points in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do left outer joins for this:

```
Select person.name, person.age, employee.yearsofservice
from person
join employee on person.name = employee.name
left outer join fulltimeemployed on person.name = fulltimeemployed.name
left outer join parttimeemployed on person.name = parttimeemployed.name
where fulltimeemployed.manager = 'Rob'  or parttimeemployed.manager = 'Rob'
```

Comment: you just changed the left joins to inner joins.

Answer (score 3):

```
select person.name, person.age, employee.yearsofservice
from person
join employee on person.name = employee.name
join (
  select name from fulltimeemployed where manager = 'Rob'
  union all select name from parttimeemployed where manager = 'Rob') employed
on person.name = employed.name
```

Comment: Yes, the result set has to be restricted somehow (which is the problem with the `left join` answers).

Comment: Thank you - your answer was helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

I question the need to have an employee table and then two different tables for full vs. parttime as well as the wisdom of joining on names, but this would work as well (notice I join fulltimeemployed and parttimeemployed to employee and not person):

```
Select
    p.name
    ,p.age
    ,e.yearsofservice
from person AS p
join employee AS e on p.name = e.name
left outer join fulltimeemployed AS ft on p.name = ft.name
    AND ft.Manager = 'Rob'
left outer join parttimeemployed AS pt on p.name = pt.name
    AND pt.manager = 'Rob'
```

Comment: This query will return all employees (left join keeps all rows from the left table used in the join).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select person.name, person.age, employee.yearsofservice
from person
join employee on person.name = employee.name

left join fulltimeemployed on person.name = fulltimeemployed.name
and  fulltimeemployed.manager = 'Rob'
left join parttimeemployed on person.name = parttimeemployed.name
and parttimeemployed.manager = 'Rob'

where fulltimeemployed.id is not null
or fulltimeemployed.id is not null
```